# SQL Return Rows Not Referenced

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have my main table, which I will call Table1, that contains the main chunk of data. I then have four tables that reference Table1, which I will call Tables2-5, and each of these tables has a foreign key that references Table1's Id as well as a DateTime column which represents when the row was created, which I will call CreatedOn.

What I would like to do is return every row from Table1 that is not referenced in Tables2-5 where the CreatedOn is within the past 90 days.

I've attempted the following:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Table1.*
FROM   Table1
LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2
    ON Table1.Id = Table2.Table1Id AND DATEADD(DAY, 90, Table2.CreatedOn) >= GETDATE()
LEFT OUTER JOIN Table3
    ON Table1.Id = Table3.Table1Id AND DATEADD(DAY, 90, Table3.CreatedOn) >= GETDATE()
LEFT OUTER JOIN Table4
    ON Table1.Id = Table4.Table1Id AND DATEADD(DAY, 90, Table4.CreatedOn) >= GETDATE()
LEFT OUTER JOIN Table5
    ON Table1.Id = Table5.Table1Id AND DATEADD(DAY, 90, Table5.CreatedOn) >= GETDATE()
WHERE
    Table2.Table1Id IS NULL
OR
    Table3.Table1Id IS NULL
OR
    Table4.Table1Id IS NULL
OR
    Table5.Table1Id IS NULL
```

But this seems to return **every** row from Table1 whenever I would expect for it to return (much) less. What I don't understand is that if I run the query doing one `LEFT OUTER JOIN` at a time then it produces the desired results, it is only when I attempt to do them all at the same time.

Comment: the specification isn't entirely clear, what should be returned when there is a matching row in Table2 but no matching row in Table5 ? if we want rows from Table1 that don't have any matching rows found in any of the tables, we probably want to use `AND` in place of `OR`   ( or negate  `WHERE NOT ( Table2.TableId IS NOT NULL OR Table3.TableId IS NOT NULL ... )`

Comment: It's a LEFT JOIN. Of course it will return every row of Table1.

Comment: @spencer7593 using the `AND` operator solved the issue. I guess I don't understand why we'd use an `AND` here instead of an `OR`, my thought was "if it doesn't appear in 2 or 3 or 4 or 5 then return the row" EDIT - After rereading my statement I can see why now.

Comment: @forpas of course...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@David the reason for AND not OR is OR will return any record that doesn't have a record in 2 or 3 or 4 or 5.  AND will return only records that don't have ANY records in 2,3,4,5.

Another way to think about this and could be potentially perform a bit better is to use
`NOT EXISTS` in the `WHERE` so:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM
    Table1 t1
WHERE
     NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Table2 t2 WHERE t1.TableId = t2.TableId AND DATEADD(DAY, 90, t2.CreatedOn) >= GETDATE())
    AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Table3 t3 WHERE t1.TableId = t3.TableId AND DATEADD(DAY, 90, t3.CreatedOn) >= GETDATE())
    AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Table4 t4 WHERE t1.TableId = t4.TableId AND DATEADD(DAY, 90, t4.CreatedOn) >= GETDATE())
    AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Table5 t5 WHERE t1.TableId = t5.TableId AND DATEADD(DAY, 90, t5.CreatedOn) >= GETDATE())
```